# Is there another definition of the word « l'indisposition »?

Tags: définition

The English word “indisposition” has the following two definitions

1. Mild illness.
2. Lack of enthusiasm or inclination.

*Please see attachment (1)*

One of the definitions of the French word « indisposition » is [*« Légère altération de la santé ».*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/indisposition/42648)

Does the French word « indisposition » also has the meaning “lack of enthusiasm or inclination”?  If so, can you show your source please?

I’m asking this question because one of the definitions of the French adjective **indisposé(e)** est [*« Qui est dans de mauvaises dispositions à l’égard de quelqu’un. Je l’ai trouvé assez indisposé contre vous. »*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9I0954)

---

*attachment (1)*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This word, with that second meaning, is very probably quite rare  nowadays. It is not found in the following dictionaries.

- [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/indisposition/42648), [Internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/indisposition/), [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/indisposition), [Notretemps](https://dictionnaire.notretemps.com/definitions/indisposition-49463), [Cordial](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/indisposition.php), …

It is found in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/indisposition), however.

> B. − Au fig. Disposition peu favorable à l'égard de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose.
> Je voudrais bien pourtant n'apporter point à la lecture de ces Cahiers de Barrès cette indisposition de l'esprit qui ne le laisse plus sensible qu'aux tares (Gide, Journal,1931, p. 1064).

I am not familiar with this word in that second sense; it seems that nowadays   would be used to express that idea,  instead, the phrase "mauvaises dispositions" or "dispositions peu favorables" and others such phrases in which "disposition is used with a negative modifying expression.

- **mauvaises dispositions de qqn [à l'égard de/contre] qqn**
- (*also, less negative, see TLFi*)  **Disposition peu favorable à l'égard de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose**

- [ref., 2006](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8VBbp6z2jJgC&pg=PA354&dq=%22mauvaises+dispositions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim05mRk4PuAhUNCxoKHTQHDB4Q6AEwBXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mauvaises%20dispositions%22&f=false) Il s ' en étonna , sans penser qu'il avait été démasqué. Le soir, quand ils revinrent à leur gîte, Lancelot dit à Bohort : – Avez-vous remarqué les mauvaises dispositions du roi à mon endroit ?
- [ref., 1977](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ZbMJAQAAIAAJ&q=%22mauvaises+dispositions%22&dq=%22mauvaises+dispositions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim05mRk4PuAhUNCxoKHTQHDB4Q6AEwG3oECEIQAg) Dans le contexte de Mc , il semble désigner les mauvaises dispositions à l'égard de Jésus , aussi bien des Pharisiens ( cf. 2–3,6 ; 7,113 ; 8,11-13 ) que d'Hérode ( cf. 6,14-29 ) . Les disciples risquent de partager ces mauvaises dispositions ...
- [ref., 1966](https://books.google.fr/books?id=X28JAQAAIAAJ&q=%22mauvaises+dispositions%22&dq=%22mauvaises+dispositions%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim05mRk4PuAhUNCxoKHTQHDB4Q6AEwInoECE0QAg) On cherche une occasion de reprendre l'interpellation afin d'accentuer les mauvaises dispositions de la Chambre contre le gouverneur.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, *indisposition* also means being *unavailable* mostly for health related issues but also for reasons that you or the person saying the word is not willing to disclose.